# What does regex expression match pattern "\\[.*\\]" mean?

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I am new to regex. What does regex expression match pattern  "\[.*\]" mean?

If I have a text like "Hello [Here]", then success is returned in the match. And match contain [Here].

I read that:

`.` indicates Any except \n (newline),
`*` indicates 0 or more times

I don't understand the "\". It believe it is just escape sequence for "\".

So, is the expression "\[.*\]" trying to match a pattern like `\[Any text\]`?

Comment: There is no `\.` in your pattern. It's `\[` to match `[` literal as `[` in regex is character class, it need to escaped to match opening square bracket.

Comment: _is the expression "\[.*\]" trying to match a pattern like [Any text] ?_ Yes. It'll match text wrapped inside square brackets. But fail when there is nested brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. It will match any characters enclosed in `[]`. The `.*` imply any or no characters enclosed in [].
Also you should try this [link](https://regex101.com/) which is a very helpful regex tool. You can input the regex pattern and check for matches easily.

Comment: Thanks! But what is the significance of backslash (\\) in the expression "\\[.*\\]"?

Comment: Backslash forces a special regex character to be interpreted literally.

Comment: Here's a good site for regex: http://misc.yarinareth.net/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/), here is a screen shot:

[image]